# edit div tag in a webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to make an Android app with a webview in which I have an html page.  This one contains a "div" tag with the `contentEditable` property set to true.

My problem: by launching the app, I can't edit the text.

I've been doing a lot of searches on Google but there was nothing on this topic. I was wondering if there was any permission missing (as the one to reach the net in the manifest) but I'm able to edit input and textarea tags (among others). I've refered to the WebView's API, WebViewClient, WebChromeClient but I didn't find any method which would configure a particular permission in order to do that.

Does the webview understand the `contentEditable` property? It's not working, even if the webview is supposed to interpret html.

My activity:

```
public class WebAppStackOverFlowActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView) ;
        webView.setWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient()) ;
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html") ;
    }
}
```

My `asset/www/index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="name" value="this is an input tag" />
    <br />
    <div contenteditable="true">this is an editable div tag</div>
    <br />
    <textarea rows="" cols="">this is a textarea tag</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

My `main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentEditable` is supported by the default browser on Android version 3.0 (Honeycomb) and up ([source](http://caniuse.com/#search=contentEditable)).

So, if you're running this on Gingerbread, that would explain why it's not working.

Comment: I am running my app on Froyo (2.2) and now it's working. I added to my code a OnKeyListener and it blocked the edition of div tag, I don't know why. And now I don't know how to listen enter key, for example.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So, you say that you got `contenteditable` to work on 2.2?  How?  I'm trying to get it to work in our app to support users of older phones.